# Django model inheritance and select_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-inheritance

I have the following in models and run into strange behavior when i use select_related and model inheritance:

Models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field_fk = models.ForeignKey('C')

class B(A):
    fields_b = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class C(models.Model):
    field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So A has a foreign key to C and B inherits from A.
Now I want to query A downcast it to B and read the relationship to C. To minimize sql queries I use `select_related`:

```
obj = A.objects.select_related('b', 'field_fk).first()
obj = obj.b          
print(obj.field_fk)  # this prints "C object"
```

Because I use `select_related` this should result in just one query. But somehow the information is lost during downcasting and I get to sql queries:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "base_a" INNER JOIN "base_c" ON 
      ( "base_a"."field_fk_id" = "base_c"."id" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN "base_b" ON 
      ( "base_a"."id" = "base_b"."a_ptr_id" ) ORDER BY "base_a"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

SELECT ••• FROM "base_c" WHERE "base_c"."id" = 1
```

So in the first query looks fine. But I am surprised that I get  a second query. 
Is this a bug in django's ORM or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned I submitted a ticket at django-project. 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25173

This is now considered as a bug and will hopefully be fixed soon.

A suggested workaround is:

```
 obj = obj.b        
 print (obj.a_ptr.field_fk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You reassign the `obj` variable, so what you basically do is this:

`print(obj.b.field_fk)`

while `.b.field_fk` is not being selected as a related object. So either add that into `select_related`, or reuse the pre-fetched object before reassigning the `obj` variable

Comment: You are right, but I still think that this is a bug.
This way using select_related with model inheritance is kind of useless. 
I opened a ticket at django-project. I hope this will be fixed soon:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25173